# How to include dashes in code block in Hugo Markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, hugo

I'm using Hugo and using VSCode as my editor.

Within that I am hoping to show the output of a PowerShell command in another code block. The Markdown code I am using is:

```
{{< highlight plaintext "linenos=false" >}}
ResourceGroupName ServerName     AllowedFQDN
----------------- ----------     -----------
ResourceGroupName SqlServerName  SqlServer2.database.windows.net
{{< / highlight >}}
```

However, when I save the file, the line of dashes as the header divider is changed to just 3 dashes as follows:

```
{{< highlight plaintext "linenos=false" >}}
ResourceGroupName ServerName AllowedFQDN

---

ResourceGroupName SqlServerName SqlServer2.database.windows.net
{{< / highlight >}}
```

On the page it also renders like this. On inspection of the HTML I see:

```
<div class="highlight"><pre tabindex="0" class="chroma"><code class="language-plaintext" data-lang="plaintext"><span class="line"><span class="cl">ResourceGroupName ServerName AllowedFQDN
</span></span><span class="line"><span class="cl">
</span></span><span class="line"><span class="cl">---
</span></span><span class="line"><span class="cl">
</span></span><span class="line"><span class="cl">ResourceGroupName SqlServerName SqlServer2.database.windows.net</span></span></code></pre></div>
```

I have tried escaping the row with both a `\` and a `` ` `` but these render with the escape character at the start of the row of dashes like this:

```
ResourceGroupName ServerName AllowedFQDN
`----------------- ---------- -----------
ResourceGroupName SqlServerName SqlServer2.database.windows.net
```

or this

```
ResourceGroupName ServerName AllowedFQDN
\----------------- ---------- -----------
ResourceGroupName SqlServerName SqlServer2.database.windows.net
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="highlight"><pre tabindex="0" class="chroma"><code class="language-plaintext" data-lang="plaintext"><span class="line"><span class="cl">ResourceGroupName ServerName AllowedFQDN
</span></span><span class="line"><span class="cl">\----------------- ---------- -----------
</span></span><span class="line"><span class="cl">ResourceGroupName SqlServerName SqlServer2.database.windows.net</span></span></code></pre></div>
```

I can edit the file outside of VSCode and it displays correctly so I believe it to be more likely with how VSCode is handling the Markdown rather than how Hugo is rendering it.

Is there any options that I can configure so that it is properly rendered as:

```
ResourceGroupName ServerName AllowedFQDN
----------------- ---------- -----------
ResourceGroupName SqlServerName SqlServer2.database.windows.net
```

Comment: I also use VS Code and after I changed `{{< / highlight >}}` to `{{< /highlight >}}` (removed space after `/`) in your code, this worked for me. What version of Hugo are you using? And what, if anything, have you specified in your config file for `markup` which is discussed on https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup/